# How would I test two methods that use shared private/public method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, spring-test

```
public class A {
    public List<Model> getModels() {
        List<Model> models = (some logic to find all models...)
        models.forEach(model -> doSharedLogic(model));
    }

    public Model getModel(int id) {
        Model model = (some logic to find Model by Id...)
        doSharedLogic(model);
    }    

    private void doSharedLogic(Model model) {
        // manipulations with model...       
    }
}
```

Let's say I have the code above. I want to unit test public API (getModels and getModel methods). They use shared logic extracted into separate method doSharedLogic().

**Question:** How to correctly test those two methods if basically logic is completely the same?
**My assumptions: **
test getModel method with testing of all possible results for doSharedLogic();
do same for getModels();

But it's going to cause duplication of code in tests.
If I just test doSharedLogic as part of one of those public methods(for example: getModel()), I can't be sure that somebody won't come later, change something and break code in second method(getModels()) by removing shared logic for example

My assumptions: test getModel method with testing of all possible results for doSharedLogic();do same for getModels();

Answer (score 0):

I would test each method for what they do and avoid duplication.

- You have getModel() which gets a single instance.   Test it for cases related to getting one instance including edge cases such as not found.  If this code is also doing data transformation, then here is where I would test that the data is correct after the transformation, probably using a mock to inject data.
- You have getModels() which gets multiples - all of them probably if it doesn't take some query string.   Test it for cases that return multiple models, including the single or empty case.   As this code is just calling getModel() under the covers, you should not reproduce any transformation logic tests and focus on testing the additional logic of "get many".

If you are really worried about someone changing the lgoic of getModels() later to not call getModel(), I would put that in comments in getModel() so that future editors know that if they remove that dependency they may need to add additional tests.

I would definitely not add a bunch of duplicative data transformation tests in both.